# difficulty with deleting a function from jquery snippet

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get rid of a function that appends a loading gif while the script is busy ajax'ing in new content, but I keep breaking the script so I'm posting it here hoping someone can just kindly edit it for me correctly. (I'd like to get rid of everything that has to do with #load and keep everything else intact.)

```
    $('#header_nav_content_container a, a.scroll_to_top, a.clear_banner, a.desire').not('.exception').click(function(){ 

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide(1555,'easeInOutQuint',loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();
    $('body').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn(888);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);  
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(777,'',hideLoader);
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(888);
    }
    return false;

});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you want the above script but without any of the loading icon references?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. I'll post it here because I know a lot of folks are using this same script ("load in and animate content" from nettuts) so someone might want to know how to get rid of the loading part of the script.

```
    $('#header_nav_content_container a, a.scroll_to_top, a.clear_banner, a.desire').not('.exception').click(function(){ 

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  
    $('#content').hide(1555,'easeInOutQuint',loadContent);  
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);  
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(777,'');  //problem: I needed to remove "hideLoader"
    }
    return false;

});
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Dude! you beat me to it! Working with code from my phone is way too slow...haha

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#header_nav_content_container a, a.scroll_to_top, a.clear_banner, a.desire').not('.exception').click(function(){ 

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide(1555,'easeInOutQuint',loadContent);  



    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);  
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(777,'');
    }

    }
    return false;

});
```